# What are the consequences of running php artisan ui a second time in the same project?

Tags: laravel, laravel-artisan

I'm new to Laravel. I'm developing an app in Laravel6 using VSCode on Windows 10.

When I started my app, I executed this command:

```
php artisan ui bootstrap --auth
```

Then I proceeded to develop my views using bootstrap4. If I executed this command now, after having created various views that used bootstrap, what would happen?

```
php artisan ui vue --auth
```

I'm hoping to hear that absolutely nothing will happen to my existing views and the necessary vue modules have simply been installed so that I could proceed to write new views that use vue instead of bootstrap.

But rather than trying it and potentially erasing my bootstrap code (or making it unrunnable because the bootstrap packages have been deleted), I thought I'd ask here. I'm guessing someone here is aware of what will happen if I run php artisan vue a second time for the same project but with a different parameter.

Comment: I believe it just replaces your files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes i have tried with commands given by you if i run "php artisan ui vue" it will only replace those files which has been generated by command and if run "php artisan ui vue --auth" it will ask me whether or not i want to replace those files means "yes/no" in a terminal.